# Convert Kafka Stream word-count example to output JSON Objects

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I'm working through the word count example, and currently have:

```
    stream.flatMapValues(value -> Arrays.asList(WORD_PATTERN.split(value.getMessage().toLowerCase())))
          .groupBy((key, value) -> value).count(Named.as("word_counts")).toStream()
          .to(KafkaTopicConfig.xxx3_REPLY_TOPIC);
```

It's my understanding from the docs, that this is going to produce a `KTable<String, Long>` and the content in the reply topic will be:

```
the 3
cat 4
etc.
```

Not even sure if this is good practice (if its not, let me know lol)... but I'm trying to make it into a more "usable" json format:

```
  [
    { 
      "word": "the", 
      "count": "3" 
    },
    { 
      "word": "cat", 
      "count": "4" 
    }
  ]
```

is this doable? I get streams are never ending, so it'll keep sending jsons in this format...

I've defined a class WordCountPairDto that holds the String, Long pair and I guess I'm trying to serialize the stream into a `ArrayList<WordCountPairDto>` and let the Json serde serialize it out to Json.

Any pointers would be appreciated!

Comment: So as I understand, you are doing the wordcount demo and got the desired results, but in your target topic, you want to push JSON, right?

Comment: In a more complex example, you can publish a message containing any number of fields, but in this example where the message key is likely the word, and the value is likely the count, isn't this all you need?

Comment: @JanHeld Yes, exactly. I can transform it at some other point before sending it to the user, but I wanted to try just push it out to the topic as the shown Json. All my topics are Json based...

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're using Spring Kafka since you tagged the question with Spring. Spring Kafka can handle the serialization/deserialization of any pojo class type for you if you subclass JsonSerializer and configure it in your properties for value.serializer.

Then you can use KafkaTemplate to produce your message type:

```
@Autowired
private KafkaTemplate<String, YourPojo> kafkaTemplate;
```

and produce with:

```
this.kafkaTemplate.send("your.topic", yourMessage);
```

Consuming is similar, extend JsonDeserializer and configure it in your properties for value.deserializer, then consume with:

```
@KafkaListener(topic="yourTopic")
public void consume(YourPojo yourPojo){ ... }
```

The serialization of your YouPojo instance for sending messages, and deserialization of messages back into instances of YourPojo is handled for you.

Comment: Yes, I am using Spring Kafka... KafkaListener is traditional.  I am working with Kafka Streams now.

Answer (score 0):

Your output would not be a JSON Array. It would be two messages with any key.

You can get that output like so

```
stream.flatMapValues(value -> Arrays.asList(WORD_PATTERN.split(value.getMessage().toLowerCase())))
      .groupBy((key, value) -> value).count(Named.as("word_counts")).toStream()
      .map(this::createJSONMessage)
      .to(KafkaTopicConfig.xxx3_REPLY_TOPIC);
```

Where you define `public KeyValueMapper<String, String, KeyValue<String, String>> createJSONMessage(String key, String value)` method to **return** your JSON Object string as the value

You can also use `Produced.with` to define different serdes.